# Getting objects with maxBy with same values

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, maxby

I have this array:

```
const obj = [
  {
    value: 1,
    position: 1,
    id: 333,
  },
  {
    value: 1,
    position: 2,
    id: 222,
  },
];
```

I'm using maxBy from lodash to get the max value of the attribute called *value*.

```
_.maxBy(obj, "value");
```

So, the problem is that there are two objects with the same *value* attribute and the *maxBy* is showing me the last object. In this case, I would need to make the *maxBy* and the same time, referring the less value to the *position* attribute.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

`_.maxBy` accepts `iteratee` as second params, we can custom the `iteratee`. Your current way is using the `_.property` iteratee shorthand.

The solution for your case:

```
const arr = [
  {
    value: 1,
    position: 1,
    id: 333,
  },
  {
    value: 1,
    position: 2,
    id: 222,
  },
];

const result = _.maxBy(arr, (i) => {
  const isDuplicate = _.filter(arr, (o) => o.value === i.value).length;
  return i.value - (isDuplicate ? i.position : 0); // get max value of (i.value - i.position) when we get duplicate case.
});
console.log(result);
```

> In your case, to get max value of `(i.value - i.position)`, we need max value of
> `value` and min value of `position`.